# Filling in the card expiry date from transaction data

Tags: php, comparative-review, e-commerce

I'm integrating my app with a payment gateway, and have the following code which returns an array to populate the transaction info:

```
function populate_transaction_info($data)
{
  extract($this->extract_model_data($data));

  // set to empty array to ensure run-able code
  $transaction_info = [];

  return array_merge($transaction_info, [
    'pan' => $card_data['card_number'],
    'expdate' => $this->build_expiry_date_string($card_data['card_exp']),
    'cust_id' => $person['email'],
    // ... more params here, not relevant for question
  ]);
}

// shown for context / run-ability
function extract_model_data($data)
{
  return [
    'person' => $data['Person'],
    'card_data' => $data['CreditCard']],
  ];
}
```

My question pertains to the `build_expiry_date_string()`, defined as:

```
function build_expiry_date_string($card_expiry)
{
  return $card_expiry['month'] . substr($card_expiry['year'], -2);
}
```

I'm passing `$card_data['card_exp']` into the function, but I'm wondering if the function itself should be the only thing that knows that it needs to look in the `card_exp` index of the array? So for example, should I refactor as:

```
...
'expdate' => $this->build_expiry_date_string($card_data),
...

function build_expiry_date_string($card_data)
{
  return $card_data['card_exp']['month'] . substr($card_data['card_exp']['year'], -2);
}
```

If yes, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first version of `build_expiry_date_string()` will be able to build an shorter notation date from any date array. I would therefore rename it to `build_short_date_string()`.

The second version actually is named correctly, but can *only* convert an expiry date to the shorter notation.

Which is the better version?

Well, clearly, if you need to create a short date string from more than one date array then the first one wins. The second one is more specialized. It will only work for the `card_exp` date.

In general I don't see the point of overspecializing functions. The more general purpose version does a good job, so I would prefer that one, even if it is, for now, only used for one date array.

**Functions should be used to encapsulate functionality that can be reused and therefore make your code easier to maintain.** ([reference](https://www.guru99.com/functions-in-php.html))

It is the *reusability* that wins for me here, over any other considerations.

Note that we're talking about simple functions here, not methods that are part of classes. OOP is a whole other can of worms.

Some other remarks about your code (this is code review afterall):

- You `extract()` data at the beginning of `populate_transaction_info()`. This seems like a nice trick, but it makes your code harder to read and debug. For instance, I have to assume that `$person` is one of these extracted variables, but for me it appears out of thin air. You could help your code reader by using a prefix whenever your extract something: `extract(...., EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'model');` and then use `$model_person`, but preferably just explicitly define the person variable in the function.
- Your comment: *"set to empty array to ensure run-able code"* and the subsequent `array_merge()` make no sense to me. Why not just define the array?

Comment: Amen to not endorsing `extract()`.  I have never had a reason to use, nor do I ever hope to use `extract()` in any project, ever.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I really appreciate it! I will rename and keep the first version for re-usability. I also knew I was going to get called out for using extract, heh. I will be more explicit about pulling the appropriate variables out of `$data`. Finally, the comment was just for this example... `$transaction_info` is initialized with some data called from another function, but I didn't feel it was super necessary to include here. Sorry for the confusion.